# how can I use curly braces in a mysql query?

Tags: syntax, mysql

I tried to do this:

```
 INSERT INTO test123 VALUES(Some text, 'More Text (and in braces.)');
```

but it doesn't work. The braces in the string

```
 'More Text (and in braces.)'
```

cause the syntax error. How can I make it work - I need mysql to accept the braces.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the syntax error is more likely caused by the fact that "Some text" isn't in quotes. Try fixing that first.

MySQL's syntax errors can be rather vague at times; it probably pointed you to a region of your query rather than the particular tripping spot.

Also, `{}` are curly braces. `()` are parentheses or brackets, depending on which type of English you're speaking :)

Comment: its ok, I have a primary key.
this works: INSERT INTO test123 VALUES(Some text, 'More Text and in braces.');

Comment: ...it does? Because it looks like it most definitely shouldn't. Check your table to make sure that you're getting the desired results - is there something about a primary key that would allow non-quoted string? If so, that sounds like a really pointless "feature."